# how to package PMML files for versioning?

Tags: predictive-modeling

I am looking to package PMML file generated to export tree model. 
Are there any existing standards which describe how to package and version PMML files ?

Comment: Probably naive suggestion: it is an xml, so why not use standard version control like git or svn?

Comment: but lets say we want use it within project as artifact then ?